# Detect main colors of object on plain background in Python

Tags: python, colors, k-means

I wrote an algorithm that detects the main colors of an image with 1 object assuming the background is plain. Here are the basic steps I'm currently running:

- run a k-means algorithm (k = 10) on the entire image
- remove the points that have the same class as pixel (0,0)
- run a new k-means algorithm with the remaining points (k = 3) = > 3 main colors

Although it's probably not the most clever algorithm, I am very satisfied with the results except when a large part of the object has the same color as the background. For instance, when the object is mainly white on a white background, the algorithm naturally tends to classify the object's white points with the background.

How would I go to have a general method (I have no prior knowledge on the object being white) that works in all cases? It's alright to assume that the object is centered both horizontally and vertically. However, nothing can be assumed about the shape of the object or the number of colors in it (sometimes it is plain, sometimes it has many different colors). Thanks !

(I believe I have read all possible related posts!)

EDIT: 
Typical result I get: 
[image: problematic case]

And that's how the first k-means classifies the points (left: k = 10, right: k= 3):
[image: k-means results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

1) If the background color is constant (e.g., all pixels are the same color) you could find the background by finding the largest component that is spatially connected and contains pixels that are all the same (or same within some threshold) color. You could remove the background, and then run K-Means on the remaining image.

2) If components from the image belong to the same cluster as the background, but aren't connected in the image, you could split them by running a connected components algorithm. Alternatively, if you aren't including spatial information when you run K-Means (e.g., the pixel coordinates) you could do that.

3) You could also try increasing K until the object splits from the background (for most/all of your images).

Comment: Good points. I also had come to the conclusion that increasing K could help. It does, I'm satisfied with the results when K > 20. However your other ideas are also insightful (haven't tested them yet!). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You weren't very clear about what the current problem is.  Could you post a screenshot?

Perhaps you mean the areas near the edge of the object (between object and background) are being incorrectly classified as background color, i.e. your algorithm is clipping too much.  In that case, you could use an edge detection algorithm in order to detect the boundary between object and background.  Once you know the edges, you know the interior, so therefore you should be able to cut out everything except that interior, and then re-run your algorithm.

If you mean that the interior of the object is being classified as background, then you could do a floodfill algorithm.  If you floodfill each region it's trying to classify, reject any region that can't floodfill all the way to pixel (0,0).  That should leave you with a list of regions that don't overlap the object.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I posted the results for a typical problematic case. The interior is indeed what is spuriously classified as background. Even so, detecting the edges should work as well, shouldn't it?